# How to split my parameter into two text boxes as labels in angular?how will i display in html after click checkbox?

Tags: angular, split

I have been trying this but i am not getting, How can i split my string into two text boxes.this is my string which is coming from backend.
template_parameter: "namespace,resources".

ts

```ts
changeSelection(event: any) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((product, index) => {

      if (product.isChecked == true) {

        let splitstring = product.template_parameter
        let sepratedArray = splitstring.split(" ");
        console.log(sepratedArray[0]);
        console.log(sepratedArray[1]);

        return product.isChecked

      }

    });
```

html

```html
 <div class="pb-3 pl-3" *ngFor="let product of selectedItemsList">
   <h4 class="fw-500 fw-b">
     <a (click)="openCaseDetails(product.id)">{{ product.template_parameter}}</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try with `splitstring.split(",");`

The 0th element would be namespace and 1st element would be resources.

Comment: Thank you Nikhil, It worked, But how will i display that in html file as labels?

Comment: You have an array in ```seperatedArray```. Just use seperatedArray[0] and seperatedArray[1] in <label> tag

Comment: I did it Nikhil, Thank you.